# JavaScript onclick event stops working after first click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a customized selection menu. The logic is quite simple: there's a div tag (styled like an input field) configured to open up another div tag (which includes a list of entries) onclick. The user then selects an entry from the menu causing the menu itself to disappear and the selected entry to be displayed in the input div tag. The problem is that any click after the first one on the input div doesn't open up the menu div again.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="destination">
<div class="list">
  <p class="body" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseleave="back(this)" onclick="select(this)">Body1</p>
  <p class="body" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseleave="back(this)" onclick="select(this)">Body2</p>
  <p class="body" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseleave="back(this)" onclick="select(this)">Body3</p>
  <p class="body" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseleave="back(this)" onclick="select(this)">Body4</p>
  <p class="body" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseleave="back(this)" onclick="select(this)">Body5</p>
  <p class="body" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseleave="back(this)" onclick="select(this)">Body6</p>
</div>
</body>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#destination{
  margin: 10% auto;
  width: 14.15em;
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: transparent;
}

.list{
  display: none;
  width: 10em;
  height: 5em;
  overflow:scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: .5em;
  background:white;
  position: relative;
  left: 10.5%;
  top:-105%;
}

.body{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
  padding:.25em;
}

.visible{
  display:inherit;
}
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
// identify the input div
let destination = document.getElementById('destination');

// identify the menu div
let list = document.querySelector('.list');

// display the menu div onclick by modifying its class attribute
destination.addEventListener('click',function(){
    list.classList.toggle('visible');
});

// just a few animations
function highlight(elem){
    elem.style.cssText = "background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); transition: background .5s linear";
}
function back(elem){
    elem.style.cssText = "background: inherit; transition: background .5s linear";
}

// when any entry is selected, hide the menu div and 
// display the entry in the input div
function select(elem){
  list.classList.toggle('visible');
  destination.innerHTML = elem.innerText;
  destination.style.cssText = "padding-top: .35em; padding-left: 5.75em;"
}
```

I can't get any useful message from the browser console (no errors), the code seems syntactically correct.

Comment: When you click on an option the first time you change the innerHTML property of the "destination" element which effectively deletes all of its children. that is why you can't see the "menu" again. it does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Check childNodes length of destination div
2. If length > 1, then toggle list class - visible
3. If length = 1, then append list, as it will be cleared by innerHTML from **select** method on dropdown select

`destination.addEventListener('click',function(){
  if(this.childNodes.length > 1){
       list.classList.toggle('visible'); 
  }else{
    this.append(list);

  }
});`

**Issue:** With innerHTML on click of dropdown list , you are overwriting childNodes of destination div and thereby removing list .
On second click, list is not available to display.

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YoaxGY

working code sample

```js
let destination = document.getElementById('destination');

let destination2 = document.getElementById('sub-destination');

let list = document.querySelector('.list');

destination.addEventListener('click',function(){
  if(this.childNodes.length > 1){
       list.classList.toggle('visible'); 
  }else{
    this.append(list);    
  }
});

// on hover + transition
function highlight(elem){
    elem.style.cssText = "background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); transition: background .5s linear";
}
function back(elem){
    elem.style.cssText = "background: inherit; transition: background .5s linear";
}

function select(elem){
  list.classList.toggle('visible');
  destination.innerHTML = elem.innerText;
  destination.style.cssText = "padding-top: .35em; padding-left: 5.75em;"
}
```

```css
#destination{
  margin: 10% auto;
  width: 14.15em;
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: transparent;
}  

.list{
  display: none;
  width: 10em;
  height: 5em;
  overflow:scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: .5em;
  background:white;
  position: relative;
  left: 10.5%;
  top:-105%;
}

.body{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
  padding:.25em;
}

.visible{
  display:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="destination">
  <div class="list">
  <p class="body" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseleave="back(this)" onclick="select(this)">Body1</p>
  <p class="body" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseleave="back(this)" onclick="select(this)">Body2</p>
  <p class="body" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseleave="back(this)" onclick="select(this)">Body3</p>
  <p class="body" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseleave="back(this)" onclick="select(this)">Body4</p>
  <p class="body" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseleave="back(this)" onclick="select(this)">Body5</p>
  <p class="body" onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseleave="back(this)" onclick="select(this)">Body6</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That's a big step forward, although I can't figure out how to preserve the style of the menu div. If you select an entry, from the second click on, there's an offset that I'm struggling to fix through CSS. However, thanks for your help!

Comment: that offset is due to css in select method , removing that resets it back to normal - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YoaxGY (removed line destination.style.cssText = "padding-top: .35em; padding-left: 5.75em;")

Comment: Thanks Naga Sai, I tried that solution before, but the position of the menu div was not exactly the same plus I lost the centered text, which I wanted both to stay there. I solved by using a CCS translation: https://codepen.io/stingeredge/pen/agqQLO

Comment: Glad it works.. Thanks @AndreaRochira for confirming :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and kind replies!